# What is the origin of the term _akachinki_, borrowed into Korean as _akkajinki_? (Meaning "Mercurochrome" or "Merbromin")

Tags: etymology

There is a topical antiseptic called *Mercurochrome* or [*Merbromin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merbromin).  According to [the Korean Wikipedia article](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%A8%B8%ED%81%90%EB%A1%9C%ED%81%AC%EB%A1%AC), an alternative name for this in Korean is [아]【a】[까]【kka】[징]【jin】[끼]【kki】 (possibly also romanized as *akkajinki*), which was borrowed from Japanese 赤【あか】チンキ.

What is the origin of this Japanese term *akachinki*?

Answer (score 5):

The more formal Japanese term for generic name *Merbromin* is メ【me】ル【ru】ブ【bu】ロ【ro】ミ【mi】ン【n】, and the term for brand name *Mercurochrome* is マ【ma】ー【a】キュ【kyu】ロ【ro】ク【ku】ロ【ro】ム【mu】.  This topical antiseptic also goes by the informal name [赤]【aka】チ【chi】ン【n】, or older [赤]【aka】チ【chi】ン【n】キ【ki】.

- The [赤]【aka】 part simply expresses the sense of *red*, as the medicine is indeed red in color:
  [image: A sample picture of _Merbromin_, showing the red color of the drug.]
- The チ【chi】ン【n】 part is from older チ【chi】ン【n】キ【ki】, which in turn is an abbreviation of チ【chi】ン【n】キ【ki】テュ【tyu】ー【u】ル【ru】, a borrowing from Dutch *tinktuur*, cognate with English *tincture* (i.e.,  a solution of a medicinal substance in a liquid, usually alcohol).

The [Japanese Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AD%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%A0%E6%B6%B2) suggests that the term arose from a slang use of チ【chi】ン【n】キ【ki】 to refer more specifically to ヨ【yo】ー【o】ド【do】チ【chi】ン【n】キ【ki】, or a tincture of iodine.  Since iodine tinctures are more yellowy-brown in color, the [赤]【aka】 was added as a prefix to differentiate.